# AvalonEdit: How to make it right-to-left?

Tags: layout, right-to-left, avalonedit, icsharpcode

I'm trying to make the avalonedit right-to-left layout, so that supporting languages that are right-to-left (e.g. Arabic)

The code seems to be too large to be understood, I need at least to know where my changes would be? What are main modules of it, or some diagrams/docs clarifying each component (other than the 4 images provided with the source)

I need at least to know what are the basic components of an editor. Thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

The `TextView` class is responsible for the actual text rendering. The layout within text lines is done using the WPF `TextFormatter` (see #region BuildVisualLine in TextView.cs).

AvalonEdit already supports bidirectional text within a left-to-right paragraph, so the editor should work if you can get WPF to create right-to-left paragraphs.

I think it might be sufficient to change the `VisualLineTextParagraphProperties.FlowDirection` property.

Ideally the text view would use the value of `TextView.FlowDirection` for this, but I've seen some weird effects when using `TextView.FlowDirection` (text being mirrored). Not sure what's up with that; I'm not familiar with the way WPF works in a right-to-left context (I guess there's some auto-mirroring feature?).

Comment: Thank you very much... it is almost done! Just the problem now 1) line numbers are in the left side (if I can make it in the right)   2) When typing, the cursor remains at the far right side without move. (Best setting I've got `FlowDirection = LeftToRight`, `TextAlignment = Right`)